# How to I use custom CSS with Bootstrap 4 and Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 and rails 5, I have used render :layout => false so that my main app layout isn't on my login page but I am using Bootstrap to style the login page which works.  I have some custom css from the Bootstrap login page example and I don't know where to save it in my rails app, or how to make sure my login page (sessions#new) picks it up.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you put `layout: false`, Rails will continue to load the applications.scss. You can create a sass partial (if you're using sass) and import it in the application.scss

Comment: thanks that is very helpful.  My custom css is in sessions.scss, what do i need to do to get Rails to detect it please?

Comment: You just have to import it within `application.scss` like this: `@import "sessions";` (assuming that sessions.scss if in the same directory). Else, you have to precise the path to the file (`@import "path/to/sessions";`for instance)

Comment: Just be sure to put `@import "sessions";` below the bootstrap files so they are correctly overridden